# Add Text to Body of SharePoint List Using JSON

Tags: list-form, json-formatting, json

Is there a way to add text for instructions in the body of a list without PowerApps? I would like to change up [this JSON code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration?source=recommendations#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections) to make it possible. I'm aware that there is a "Description" section when creating a column, but I would like it to look like below where the bold would be the "field" and I am able to add description beside it.

In addition, is it possible with JSON to have a yes/no drop down with the question beside it and not as a column? And if they click "yes", it will display a multi-box entry below is (pic 2).

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the body JSON is not actual list formatting. It's a custom schema that is only used to define sections and the columns in those sections. There is no actual formatting logic available using this approach.

An alternative to Power Apps is to use SPFx but that is likely a much harder option depending on your experience level.

Comment: Oh no! Unfortunately, I am not experienced with Power Apps.